# Smoothing SKCameraNode motion using constraints

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, lerp

**Question** Is there a way to use constraints to smooth the motion of the camera?

**Detail** I recently read a [post](http://www.learn-to-code-london.co.uk/blog/2016/04/20/smoother-camera-motion-in-spritekit-using-lerp/) about smoothing camera motion using linear interpolation (lerp) and it made me wonder if I could achieve a similar effect using constraints.

One promising option I saw in the documentation was `distance(_: SKRange, toNode: SKNode)` but after some experimentation, the results aren't at all what I was hoping for. I've tried using a constant value and the upper limit/lower limit range without success.

Here is the code that keeps the camera centered on a sprite:

```
let cameraRange = SKRange(constantValue: 0.0)
let heroLocationConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(cameraRange, toNode: hero)
```

I can imagine a set of constraints that would have to be enabled/disabled based on the player's y position, but that hardly seems like the best way to go. What would be really great is a node tracking variable that implements lerp automatically!

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an `SKContraint` that does that. I suspect you'll need to implement a LP filter during the `didSimulatePhysics` step. Also, I suggest you set the position directly instead of using an `SKAction`. Since the `dSP` is called ~60 times a second, the action may not complete in time for the next cycle.

Comment: The code that keeps the camera centered on a sprite using constraints came from Apple's demo program DemoBots. It's also very easy to keep the camera within certain boundaries so you keep the focus on the game and not the empty borders. It seemed like a great solution...except for the bouncy camera motion.

Comment: why not just use SKAction.moveToX(player.x,y:player.y,duration:0.1) with a key, then as the player moves, constantly update this action.  No linear interpolation is needed

Comment: if you want, use a waitForDuration on your first move, and do not allow the move to to be updated till after the duration.  (BTW, I do not like the effects at all of the linear interpolation, it makes the platform game a lot harder to plan jumps)